# How to tell if a route is valid in React Router 4?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

In previous versions of React Router, we had the `router.match()` function which will tell us if a given path is a valid route.  How do I do the same thing in 4.0?

Context: We have links which are populated from data.  Usually, these links are valid within our router, but not all of them are.  We'd like to switch-out the `Link` with an `a` in those cases.  Specifically, the path might be an external link, in which case we know we don't want a `Link` component and passing the external link will cause the router to fail.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `Route` for that. React Router4 uses render props to give you the data you want. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods So probably something like:

```
<Route path="/somepath">{({match,location,history})=> match? <Link ..>: null}</Route>
```

This is actually how `NavLink` is implemented.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  What do I use in place of `"/somepath"`?  For example, if the path is an external link?  Or a link that isn't recognized by the router?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question, please check: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5189